# why does the Control.DrawToBitmap changes the pixelformat to DontCare?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, pixelformat

I used IlSpy to investigate the method it turned out to be designed to preserve the pixel format of the target bitmap here is the code:

```
public void DrawToBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle targetBounds)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");
        }
        if (targetBounds.Width <= 0 || targetBounds.Height <= 0 || targetBounds.X < 0 || targetBounds.Y < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("targetBounds");
        }
        if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            this.CreateHandle();
        }
        int nWidth = Math.Min(this.Width, targetBounds.Width);
        int nHeight = Math.Min(this.Height, targetBounds.Height);
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
            UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), 791, hdc, (IntPtr)30);
            using (Graphics graphics2 = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                IntPtr hdc2 = graphics2.GetHdc();
                SafeNativeMethods.BitBlt(new HandleRef(graphics2, hdc2), targetBounds.X, targetBounds.Y, nWidth, nHeight, new HandleRef(graphics, hdc), 0, 0, 13369376);
                graphics2.ReleaseHdcInternal(hdc2);
            }
            graphics.ReleaseHdcInternal(hdc);
        }
    }
```

if you check the pixel format of "bitmap" at the very end of the method after the drawing it gives the right "Pixelformat" but once you check the bitmap on which you draw the control (the one passed to the method) it give "DontCare" pixelformat.

what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: Hans didn't realise that this _is_ `Control.DrawToBitmap`.. he assumed it was your code.

Comment: Is the pixelformat of the passed in bitmap changing from some pf to dontcare? I don't see any reason why that would happen but depending how that bitmap was obtained 'dontcare' is a perfectly reasonable pf - basically that is the pf you would expect from anything coming from the screen. By not specifying an explicit pf everything defaults to a screen-compatible pf.